# Intermediate values in C++

Tags: c++

I can not find how to implement a design in C++. In the language of Delphi in case the operator can write the following design:

```
    case s[j] of
         '0'..'9','A'..'Z','a'..'z','_': doSomeThing();
```

How can i do the same in c++. Attracts me is the construction type 'a' .. 'z' and etc...

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it is impossible. You can simulate a list of values like this:

```
switch (s[j])
{
case '0':
case '1':
case '2':
case '3':
    doSomething1();
    break;
case 'a':
case 'b':
case 'c':
case 'd':
    doSomething2();
    break;
}
```

But you cannot specify ranges. You should use if-else-if if you need ranges:

```
if ( (s[j] >= '0') && (s[j] <= '9'))
    doSomething1();
else if ( (s[j] >= 'a') && (s[j] <= 'z'))
    doSomething2();
```

Anyway, *if*'s are much more safe than *switch*'s :-)

Comment: "more safe"? What does that mean?

Comment: It is less likely that a programmer will make a mistake (that compiles) in if statement that in switch. People were forgetting to put breaks in right places since C was invented. Also, switch, IMHO, is much less readable and, as already stated, less versatile.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using [isalnum](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isalnum/) function as:

```
if(isalnum(s[j]) || (s[j] == '_') )
```

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use a switch/case statement for this in C++. C++ also provides pre-built functions to test most of that, so you'd use something like:

```
if (isalnum(s[j]) || s[j]=='_')
    doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
const std::string char_set("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
if (char_set.find(s[j] != std::string::npos)
{
    doSomething();
}
```